# Mitigating Noise From Clothes When Making In-Ear Binaural Recordings Whilst Walking

Tags: recording, sound, noise

I appreciate that I'm probably asking the impossible, but I'm looking for ways to prevent in-ear binaural mics from picking up noises coming from my clothes.

I've managed to eliminate breathing by only breathing through my mouth, but I can't seem to eliminate the sound of clothes moving as I walk. I have chosen the quietest clothing possible and removed scarf and hat and chosen a coat with a low collar, but I can still hear my clothes in the background. Other than that, I'm really pleased with my recordings.

I have some Core Sound mics which I am using with low gain on the recorder.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Don't use your own ears. make a dummy head and use that. Solves the breathing problem and also the clothing noise issue. Job Done.

Comment: Thanks, but how does that solve the problem of russtling clothing? I'm still wearing clothes and walking, only now I have to carry a head everywhere.

Comment: Why don't you explain a little more what you are trying to achieve. For some reason you have got lavaliers stuck in your ears, outline a little more what you want to try and achieve by this. If you want to record binaural - best way to do it is with a static dummy head. Why do you want to carry it around with you?

Comment: http://www.dpamicrophones.com/mic-university/principles-of-the-binaural-stereo-technique

Comment: I tired a variety of binaural setups and none gave me the quality of sound I get from the Core Sound mics. I also found most binaural mics are useless when there is any wind and are too small to add any wind protection. The Core Sound mics allow me to add a muff and wear in my ears so I have no issue with wind. As I say mention in my question, I am looking for a way to reduce clothes-sound 'as I walk'. I'm not much interested in recordings where the mics are static, but I love recordings that are on the move. For me this is the perfect use of binaural mics.

Comment: I've updated the title to highlight the walking element.

Comment: Your level of success with this will depend entirely on your level of commitment. Your best bet is to wear lycra. Don't think I"m joking. I'm not. Foley artists do it all the time so that they can walk without clothing noise.

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately I'm in Venice at the moment and although my commitment to the craft is high, I'm unable to bring myself to roam the streets in a unitard. I have been experimenting with different clothes though and found it best to avoid synthetics - stick to wool and cotton. It is also crucial to eliminate all overlaps - no scarf, ditch the 3/4 length coat etc. Cut of trousers also plays an important role. Tight is good, but they need to be pulled up high rather than riding low. I'm 90% there now, but in really narrow allyways it is impossible to eliminate all clothes sound.

Comment: If you do get to the point where you are roaming the streets of Venice in a mankini, photos are mandatory or it didn't happen.

Comment: If it comes to it all you'll need is the audio. Lots of 'mama mia', 'madre di Dio' and eventually the sound of my teeth chattering giving way to sobs of shame.

Answer (score 1):

You might have luck with tailoring your wardrobe to the recording process (tight fitting, low friction, etc.). [Apparently Lycra is an common option](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40435/mitigating-noise-from-clothes-when-making-in-ear-binaural-recordings-whilst-walk/40496#comment38365_40442).

Otherwise this will have to be removed in post-production and the won't be very easy. See [my answer here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/40495/9881) for a similar suggestion; I think you'll have much better luck removing such "handling noise" in this case.